# Upgrade Gupta application from version 5.2 to 7.0

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

I'm trying to convert a gupta application from version 5.2 to the version 7.0, after that i see that there is an external functions whose name is mimg52.dll, i try to change it in mimg70.dll but there isn't any dll on my computer which this name. Then, i try to launch the application with the dll version 5.2 but the program shows me the following message:
"Gupta runtime environment could not be loaded (CDLLI52.dll)"

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have 2 issues at the same time, but one could be causing the other....

Deal with the first one first and download the correct v7.0 mimg dlls from here: [mImg and mTbl link](http://micsto.com/) , (mImg and mTbl is a 3rd party plug-in.) , or better still, from the official Gupta TeamDeveloper Community forum here: [mImg download from TD forum](https://forum.tdcommunity.net/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=73045)   ( register and you get more options ) ...

and then copy them directly into your application path ( you don't need to register the dll's ). MAKE SURE YOU USE THE CORRECT VERSION AS THEY ARE ALL IN THIS DOWNLOAD.
Then change your code from *52.dll to *70.dll .

Then we'll deal with the next issue once you are loading the correct mimg dll's, if they are not already fixed by this.